# Loading UserControl asynchronously

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I have a WPF application which loads a usercontrol (grid) in a content (MetroContentControl) area when an option is clicked:

My MetroContentControl is surrounded by a progress bar so the idea is while the usercontrol is loaded, the IsBusy Progress bar loads:

```
private void ViewQuotes_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            RadBusyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                // load datagrid control
                main.Content = new Quotes();
            }));
            //RadBusyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
}
```

However it the progress bar never displays till after the usercontrol (grid) is loaded, so my assumption of how this should work is wrong.
I know I have previously got the progress bar working as expected when loading data asyncrnously to already initliased datagrid but doesn't seem to be working in this instance 
Any ideas what the best approach to this is?

Answer (score 0):

Simply saying user control is extremely hard to render on a different thread.

First, you need to be aware that the animation of progress bar also occupies UI thread that means if your time consuming job is on UI thread, even your progress bar is showing, it does not get animated. Therefore putting a progress bar on loading user control does not work as what you expected.

Second, you put two UI operations in a event handler, WPF can only handle these UI operations after it finishes the current operation. Since you call loading user control using Dispatcher.Invoke with default priority at Normal,9 (I think), and direct call UI is at around Input,5, you see progress bar shows after user control is loaded.

Finally  you need a clear separation of sync job and async job. In your case, all UI related are sync jobs and if you have any data related time consuming job such as getting quotes, you can put them on separate thread, showing progress bar when executing the job then load user control after job is finished.